# How to make sidebar with same height as the content div?

Tags: css, height

the code is the following:

(CSS)

```
#container {
    border:1px dashed #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content, #sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
#content {
    background:yellow;
}

#sidebar {
    background:grey;
}

#sidebar {
    height:100%;
}
```

(HTML)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Few words</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to see a `#sidebar` div with same height, like the `#content` div, is it possible without absolute position? Online version: http://jsfiddle.net/yJbUW/

Comment: Im not sure if you want it as pure CSS but i made a version with jQuery for you: http://jsfiddle.net/yJbUW/1/

Comment: Nice solution @andershagbard, however also solvable with CSS. Check my answer.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20167829/1741542

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that by displaying the `#container` as table and displaying `#content` and `#sidebar` as table-cells:

```
#container {
    border:1px dashed #000;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#content, #sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width:50%;
}
```

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/yJbUW/2/).

Comment: Nowadays you would fix this with Flexbox!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below code

`CSS` goes here

```
#container {
    border:1px dashed #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content, #sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
#content {
    background:yellow;
}

#sidebar {
    background:grey;
}


#Container
{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

and update HTML as follows,

```
<div id="Container">
    <span id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
    </span>

    <span id="sidebar">
        <p>Few words</p>
    </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved with
`#content, #sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width:50%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
    display:table;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.one {
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    display:table-cell
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="one">gfhgfhgfhgf</div>
        <div class="one">gfhgfhgfhgf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code before the container closing Div, works for me!

```
<p style="clear:both;"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest and most elegant solution:

```
#container {
display:grid;
grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```