# how to stretch div based on content

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, css-float

**CSS**

```
#outer
{
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
background: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
float:inherit;
}
#main
{
display:inline;
position: relative;        
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 100%;
}

#header
{
position: relative;
padding: 28px;
height: 125px;
background: #ffffff;
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
border-bottom: solid 1px #003B47;
}
#copyright
{
padding: 40px 0 80px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #777777;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="header" style="background-color: lightgrey">
            </div>
    </div>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="sidebar" style="background-color: lightgrey">
            <div id="menubar">
                        <h2>
                            Menu
                        </h2>
            <ul class="linkedList">

                        <li>
                            <img id="img12" src="./images/bt_tri.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" runat="server"/>
                            <a href="#">Server Search</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img id="img13" src="./images/bt_tri.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" runat="server"/>
                            <a href="Service_Status.aspx">Service Status</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img id="img14" src="./images/bt_tri.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" runat="server"/>
                            <a href="Default.aspx">Data Records</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="box">
                    <h2>
                        Member Details 
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel id="Up1" runat="server">
                         <contenttemplate>
                             Last Refreshed : <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><BR /><BR />
                         <asp:GridView id="gvMem_Details" runat="server" SkinID="Professional" OnRowDataBound="gvMem_Details_RowDataBound">
                         <RowStyle Width="500px"/>       
                         </asp:GridView> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                             <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="600">
                             </asp:Timer>
                         </contenttemplate>
                         </asp:UpdatePanel><br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h2>
                        Reservation Details
                    </h2>
                    <p>                                        
                        <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <contenttemplate>
                            Last Refreshed : <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><BR /><BR />
                        <asp:GridView id="gvRes_Details" runat="server" SkinID="Professional" OnRowDataBound="gvRes_Details_RowDataBound">
                        </asp:GridView> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="600">
                            </asp:Timer>
                       </contenttemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </p>
                </div>

                </div><br class="clear" />
        </div><br class="clear" />
    </div>
    <div id="copyright">
        &copy; Company. Design by <a href="http://www.venka.com/" rel="nofollow">Technies</a>.
    </div>
  </form>
```

I have to stretch my div based on the content inside... i have head, body and copyright(lower) divs... I want body div size should be of its dynamic contents.

Comment: Can you provide html?

Comment: thanks for reply.. i have given here my aspx side codes

Comment: Please be more precise. Which div you want to stretch and based on which divs?

Comment: I want to stretch "main" div based on its contents.. Main has two divs. one is static and other is dynamic 'changing'

Comment: When you say stretch, do you mean fluid height where any div grows shrinks based on content and everything below it moves up or down?  What isn't working?  Which browser(s)?

Comment: @stinky towel: two divs inside one div.. in those two, if one div stretches its height, another div should stretch to the same height as the first one..

Comment: Sounds like your question was already answered here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763363/how-to-create-equal-height-columns-in-pure-css