# Make multiple columns share the max height of all columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I am new to bootstrap. I am using three columns with class span4 each to show some highlighted content. The boxes are with background color and a solid border. How do I set the height of all the three columns to the max height column among three?

```
<div class="row grid-row">
 <div class="span4">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <h3>Tutoring &amp; Training Centers</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-body">
    <p>World’s leading tutoring centers use to create custom diagnostic analysis to improve student performance, increase efficiency, and grow customer base.</p>
<p class="center"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="span4">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <h3>Tutoring &amp; Training Centers</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-body">
    <p>World’s leading tutoring centers use to create custom diagnostic analysis to improve student performance.</p>
<p class="center"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="span4">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <h3>Tutoring &amp; Training Centers</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-body">
    <p>World’s leading tutoring centers use to create custom diagnostic .</p>
<p class="center"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have attached a screen short for refrense.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: set min-height on .grid-row .span4

Comment: you can add a custom class to make the height constant/consistent for all the 3 div's

Comment: Just a side note - you're using an old version of Bootstrap.  Of course you may not want / be able to upgrade to latest, but thought I'd mentioned it in case you came across the old documentation accidentally.  Latest version: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: the theme I am using for my wordpress site does not support bootstrap 3.x thanks all for your replies

Answer (score 1):

There will be [an official experimental example](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13203) of same-height columns using [CSS flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) in Bootstrap v3.2.0. Here's the gist of it:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

And then use `<div class="row row-eq-height">` instead of `<div class="row">`.

Note the flexbox isn't supported in IE<10.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$("div").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$("div").height(maxHeight);
```

[With CSS](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-equal-height/)

Also check out: [How to create equal height columns in pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763363/how-to-create-equal-height-columns-in-pure-css)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

Html :

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="box">a</div>
    <div class="box">b</div>    
    <div class="box" style="height:100px;">c</div>  
</div>
```

Css :

```
.main{
    height:auto;
    display:table;

}
.box{
    height:100%;
    width:80px;
    display:table-cell;
    background:gray;
    border:1px solid red
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLUXf/)

Comment: This doesn't make the columns responsive.