# How to make two div´s next to each other have the same height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I wrote a Web Application which has three div´s.
One for the headline under that one on the left with a
menu and next to that one in which the content will be loaded.

So I don´t want to set a static width and the content´s
length changes. I have tried with `overflow:auto`
but that did not work.

**CSS**:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

.area-header {
    height:40px;
    background-color:#71A4C3;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.area-menu {
    width:300px;
    margin-left:20px;
    background-color:#8BC6EA;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.area-content {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
     <div id="area-header" class="area-header">
         <h2>A Web Application!</h2>
     </div>

        <div id="area-menu" class="area-menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                @foreach (WebApplicationWithSqlAndJS.Models.MenuItem item in Model)
                {
                    <li id="menu-item"><a href="@item.Target" onclick="return false">@item.Title</a></li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="area-content" class="area-content"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: When you say 'length', do you mean height?

Comment: Yes sorry corrected it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create equal height columns in pure CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763363/how-to-create-equal-height-columns-in-pure-css)

Comment: you could try `max-height: 300px //or whatever height it should have`

Comment: but that doesn´t make the div´s height equal

Comment: Please, show how are the HTML structured

Comment: It's working fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/01qop5sr/ .. You could go with `min-width` instead as shown in the Fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a parent div to the divs that you want to have same height.

**parent div:**

`overflow: hidden;`

**child div:**

`float: left; padding-bottom: 500em; margin-bottom: -500em;`

---

> You can get equal height columns in CSS by applying bottom padding of
>   a large amount, bottom negative margin of the same amount and
>   surrounding the columns with a div that has overflow hidden.
>   Vertically centering the text is a little trickier but this should
>   help you on the way.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1205485/2851845

---

```css
   
body
{
    margin: 0;
}

.area-header
{
    height:40px;
    background-color:#71A4C3;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#area-wrapper
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}  

.area-menu, .area-content
{
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
}

.area-menu
{
    width: 200px;  
    background-color:#8BC6EA;
}

.area-content
{
    width: 400px;  
    background-color: LightSlateGrey;  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="area-header" class="area-header">
        <h2>A Web Application!</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="area-wrapper">
        <div id="area-menu" class="area-menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id="menu-item"><a href="#" onclick="return false">@item.Title</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="area-content" class="area-content">
            <div style="height:200px;background:red;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set height of "area-content" div same as that of "area-content" div:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
                heightToSet=$("#area-menu").height();
                $("#area-content").height(heightToSet);
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: If dealing with dynamic content, or images, it would be a better idea if we use window.load instead of document.ready. In some cases, using document.ready, 0 will be returned as element's height, which will make the other element invisible.

Comment: Both suggestions have for some reason no effect on the menu or the contents length

Comment: Also remove padding-bottom:100%;height:100%; from .area-menu class